# How to make NordVPN with DD-WRT Faster?

Tags: router, vpn, dd-wrt

Router: Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (01/04/15) std. My current country: Latvia. Location of VPN server: Latvia.

I think NordVPN has better speeds than PrivateInternetAccess (PIA) in Latvia, but their manuals are worser than PIA's, for instance [here](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/dd-wrt/openvpn/) a random collection of scripts and discussions. 
I am trying to speed up NordVPN connection here.

If I keep OpenVPN client on in DD-WRT (Services > VPN > OpenVPN Client > Start OpenVPN Client enabled/disabled), my internet speed is 10x slower download/upload and ping is 20x slower although the VPN server is in the same city as I am. I used PIA too but it is much worser than NordVPN in Latvia (ping 4x worser; download 2x worser; upload 4x worser). However, some users have managed to get fast download/upload with their NordVPN and I am wondering how. 
I followed PIA's manual about VPN settings of DD-WRT [here](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/dd-wrt-openvpn) because they are much more mature than NordVPN's own ones. I substituted corresponding NordVPN's infos to appropriate places

### DD-WRT settings

My settings in Services > VPN where the server is in Latvia where username/password are just dummies

[image]

I have in Services > VPN; where I downloaded the certificates from [here](https://nordvpn.com/api/static/ca_and_tls_auth_certificates.zip)

- NordVPN single server of Latvia can be found by clicking Latvian flag [here](https://nordvpn.com/servers/) at the end; note, to found the correct IP can be confusing
- Encryption Cipher: *AES-128 CBC* but can be also *AES-256 CBC*
- TLS auth
- CA cert

In Services > Services

- DHCP Server > Used Domain: LAN & WAN
- DNSMasq > Local DNS: Enabled

In Setup > Basic Setup > Network Address Server Settings (DHCP) [PIA DD-WRT manual]

[image]

In Setup > IPV6: Disable.

### Changes after Contacting NordVPN

They do not want to enable these settings. They prefer their script. 
I cannot anymore use these settings. 
I do not understand why. 
They have made some changes by intention or without purpose.

---

How can you make internet connection faster with VPN?

Comment: This doesn't fix your issue, but perhaps you should remove the VPN username and password from the first image above.

Comment: @chuex They are just dummies. Not correct ones.